# Filter not hooking

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, filter, hook

I have some difficulties adding a filter from a plugin file.
The filter is applied in an AJAX function.
The plugin file is included correctly, as all the other code is working perfectly.
The other code in the ajax.php file works perfectly.

**ajax.php**

```
$user_meta = array(
    'lang'      =>  substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2),
    'actkey'    =>  $actkey,
);
$user_meta = apply_filters( 'add_more_meta', $user_meta, $_POST );
add_user_meta( $user_id, 'data', $user_meta );
```

**plugin-file.php**

```
function add_more_meta ( $user_meta, $var ) {
    //NOT HOOKING
    $user_meta['major'] = 'major';
    return $user_meta;
}
add_filter( 'add_more_meta', 'add_more_meta', 10, 2 );
```

The array stays the same and doesn't change.

Anyone got an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe there is more `add_filter` hooked to `add_more_meta`? Try this `add_filter( 'add_more_meta', 'add_more_meta', 1, 2 );`

Comment: @TomaszWinter Unfortunately not, I've even tried to change the hook's name

Comment: There was a ticket on make core WordPress about add_more_meta, the description: Calling an action hook from within the first action hook callback for an action hook that contains 2+ callbacks will cause the additional callbacks not to be called for the initial action calls. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your filter is added before the filter tags is applied.

### Quick Debug

```
// Print all filters before `add_more_meta` filter tag applied.
global $wp_filters;
var_dump($wp_filters);

// or check it by has_filter($tag, $function_to_check = false) function.

if(has_filter('add_more_meta', 'add_more_meta') {
var_dump('Yes, filtered');
} else {
var_dump('No, not filtered');
}

$user_meta = apply_filters( 'add_more_meta', $user_meta, $_POST );
```

### Possible Fix

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_custom_filters', 10);

function add_my_custom_filters() {
add_filter( 'add_more_meta', 'add_more_meta', 10, 2 );
}
```

wrap your custom filters and hook them to `init` action usually will make sure that the filters work properly in all places included ajax.

Comment: Really helpful answer.
My problem was that I included the plugin file at 'after_theme_setup' , but after changing it to 'admin_init' or 'init' it works perfectly. Seems like I've misunderstood [this graphic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162863/106313) by thinking that on on AJAX call all hooks before 'init' get fired

Answer (score 0):

## 1)  ask such questions at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

2) I doubt problem is with `add_user_meta( $user_id, 'data', $user_meta );`  `$user_id` seems to be undefined there (You should have pasted full codes, not the small part).